# Grails 3.3.4 Simple Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm attempting to save a record using an Ajax call in Grails 3.3.4. I've looked over other posts but none of them seem to have a resolve that has helped me.

The remote tags are deprecated in Grails 3, so that won't be any option. I also need to grab all my form fields, not individual text boxes. But it seems like my form data isn't getting passed through. Any ideas?

When I submit the form, I receive this error:

> Error 500: Internal Server Error
>
> URI /user/saveAjax
>
> Class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
>
> Message null
>
> Caused by No signature
> of method:
> com.vogella.grails.guestbook.$UserServiceImplementation.save() is
> applicable for argument types:
> (grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[controller:user,
> format:null, action:saveAjax]] Possible solutions:
> save(com.vogella.grails.guestbook.User), wait(), any(), wait(long),
> any(groovy.lang.Closure), isCase(java.lang.Object)

Domain

```
package com.vogella.grails.guestbook

class User {
    String name
    String last
    static constraints = {
    name (blank:false, nullable:false, size:3..30, matches:"[a-zA-Z1-9_]+")
    }

    String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.vogella.grails.guestbook

import grails.validation.ValidationException
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

class UserController {

    UserService userService

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    static scaffold = User

        def saveAjax(params) {
            render params
            userService.save(params)
            render "Success!"

        }
}
```

GSP

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Welcome to Grails</title>

     <g:javascript library='jquery' />

</head>
<body>


<g:form id = "my_awesome_form">
<g:textField id = "box1" name="mytextbox"/>
<g:textField id = "box2" name="mytextbox2"/>
<input type="button" id = "mybutton" onclick="changeName()" value="create user"/>
</g:form>   
<div id="resultDiv"></div>     

<script>
function changeName()
    {   event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<g:createLink url="[action:'saveAjax',controller:'User']" />",
            dataType: "json",
            type:"post",
            data: $('#my_awesome_form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                    $( "#resultDiv" ).addClass( 'alert alert-info' ).append( 'Successfully saved event' )
            }, 
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 $( "#resultDiv" ).addClass( 'alert alert-info' ).append(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When trying to call params.box1 when passing the data by

> $('#my_awesome_form').serialize();

I receive:

> Caused by Ambiguous method overloading for method
> grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper#render.
> Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class
> com.vogella.grails.guestbook.UserController, null] due to overlapping
> prototypes between: [interface
> grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer, interface
> java.lang.CharSequence] [interface
> grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer, interface
> java.util.Map]

Comment: Your save method in UserServiceImplementation takes a User object not a Map

Comment: How do I pass through a user object form my form?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you're passing a map `params` to the `userService save` method which expects a `User` object, you could either change the `userService save` method implementation so it accepts a map or just pass it on like this:

```
userService.save( new User( params ) )
```

This assumes the field ids in your form match the field names in your `User` domain so Grails is able to [bind them](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding), if not change them to match (much easier) or you'll have to manually set them like:

```
def user = new User()
user.name = params.box1
...
```

Comment: This method works if I'm grabbing each form element and passing them separately into the data field of my ajax call. If I try to call "params.box1" when passing the data using "form.serialize()" I get an error. I've updated my post with this error.

Comment: You're calling render twice, get rid of the `render params` in your controller action and leave the  `render "Success!"`

Comment: If I render "Success" it finishes without error. However, no record is actually being created. It looks like my textbox values are not getting passed through the ajax. I receive the error I posted before whenever I attempt to render a params value because my params are NULL. Any idea why my form data is going through?

Comment: So you are definitely getting to the saveAjax method? If you do `println params` as the first statement what do you see? If you're getting there, maybe there's an issue with the newly created User, how are you creating it? Try adding `user.save( failOnError: true )` when saving the user to see if you're hitting some domain constraint issue.

Comment: I changed my Ajax data arguments to pass both my serialized form and my "box1" value. When running executing "println params" on the first line of the saveAjax method, the form data is printed null, but the box1 value gets passed. The rest of the controller executed fine, so the form data being Null seems to be the only problem here.   [form:, box1:testname, controller:user, format:null, action:saveAjax]